# StripeInvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameters: 0, 3, 1, 2

Tags: node.js

solt error for sripe in nodejs StripeInvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameters: 0, 3, 1, 2

StripeInvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameters: 0, 3, 1, 2

this error is so had and i can't solve please try you if you can understand this error